# Exclude documenting every functions

Tags: c, doxygen

I am trying to generate document for my C application using doxygen, but only for the macros (#define). The INPUT header files contain both macros and some function prototypes, but I dont want Doxygen to generate documentation for the prototypes. Hence the problem. How do I generate document only with the macros? I have tried many options. EXCLUDE_PATTERN doesnt help as there are macros and prototypes which always have a common pattern, and a unique pattern may not be unique in the future. I also tried moving all my macros under specific groups (\addgroup), but couldnt find a way to exclude groups under which the function prototypes belong. 
I am sure something like this should be possible in doxygen, but I am just not able to find it (doxygen documentation/stackoverflow/general google searches). Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickest and simplest is to surround the part you do *not* want doxygen to process with `@cond` and `@endcond`.

> MACROS and stuff
>
> /** @cond */
>
> int prototypes();
>
> /** @endcond */

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works and sounds simple enough, but is this the only way? It would be just great if I can achieve this without making such a modification in my source, as I have other doxyfiles which generates documentation for APIs as well. If I use /cont I would have to enable them under ENABLED_SECTIONS for my other doxyfiles, which I would like to avoid, given a choice. Nonetheless, I appreciate this response very much.

Comment: @VishnuS What you are asking for, to exclude things like function prototypes, is contrary to what Doxygenis designed for, so I think you will require some explicit modification in the source to achieve this. If you simply and *permanently* want the  prototypes ignored then you can just use `@cond` (no parameter) and `endcond` and make no change to ENABLED_SECTIONS.